# I am not being able to post a file along with form values in vb.net using webclient method

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim oWeb As System.Net.WebClient = New System.Net.WebClient()
Dim parameters As NameValueCollection = New NameValueCollection()
Try
```

'Add parameters
        parameters.Add("fname", fname) 
        parameters.Add("dob", dob)
        parameters.Add("country", country)
        oWeb.QueryString = parameters
        'Dim responseBytes = oWeb.UploadValues(urla + "nm", "POST", parameters)
'upload file
        Dim responseBytes = oWeb.UploadFile(urla + "nm", "POST", "E:\abc.txt")
        Dim response As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseBytes)
        MessageBox.Show(response)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try

Comment: Welocme to the [so]. Your question currently does not meet minimum standards, I quote the help center: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.*  You are welcome to press [edit] link below the question and improve it.

Comment: Here's the link to [mcve]